# What is the meaning of 'llamarnos a paz'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Tenemos que crear un caos muy berraco para que **nos llamen a paz**.

Context: Pablo Escobar and his cousin Gustavo are talking about the failed negotiations of peace with the Colombian government and how to deal with the Search Block chase on them. Then, Pablo says the sentence above.

Does "llamarnos a paz" mean "to ask us for peace", "to appeal to us for peace" ? If so, could "nos llamen por paz" be used instead?

Comment: Here again it would be helpful to have more information (see the comment on your other question). My guess is they're talking about a government appeal for peace. If so, then "llamarnos por paz" would not work. However, "hacer un llamado por la paz" would work. The prep research you could do would be to check a dictionary with lots of examples for "llamar" and "llamado," and linguee for various permutations of "llamar" and "paz." // I'm voting to close for lack of research.  Give it a try, include your results in the question, and if you're still stuck I can always retract my vote.

Comment: I have added context to the question. Personally, I don't rely too much on the Linguee dictionary as I have already found wrong/unusual translations on it.

Comment: The only idiomatic sentence I can think of which is based on the pattern "llamar a + noncount noun" is "llamar a silencio". Perhaps they just used that structure to create some sort of parallelism with the idiom: instead of saying: *Tenemos que hacer mucho ruido para que nos llamen a silencio* we have *Tenemos que causar mucho caos para que nos llamen a paz* (which, truth to tell, sounds wrong).

Comment: Note there is also the [Cuerpo de Paz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuerpo_de_Paz), an agency from the USA that worked in Colombia on drug related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"nos llamen a paz" is not a correct spanish sentence. "Nos llamen para acordar la paz", "Nos pidan acordar la paz" or "Nos ofrezcan una tregua" would be better, but he is a Narco an he talk as bad as he wants